# Using bootRepackage=false in Maven

Tags: maven, spring-boot

Does anybody know what is the Gradle `bootRepackage=false` equivalent in Maven? How can you configure spring boot plugin to not generate boot war?

The problem that I face is that I have a multi module project. When I build the project with mvn clean install, the module jar contain the entire libraries defined in its pom.

Answer (score 19):

The solution above applies to older versions. Spring-boot maven plugin 1.2 introduced:

```
<properties>
    <spring-boot.repackage.skip>true</spring-boot.repackage.skip>
</properties>
```

> Skip the execution. Default value is: false. User property is: **spring-boot.repackage.skip**.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/html/#goals-repackage

and

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/html/#goals-repackage-parameters-details-skip

Comment: Today is 22/07/2020 and that link is dead

Comment: it works for me, thanks . mvn clean -Dspring-boot.repackage.skip=true

Comment: Totally smooth. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can skip the [`repackage`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.3.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html) goal from being executed by setting the [`skip`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.3.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html#skip) attribute to `true`:

> Skip the execution. Default: `false`.

In your plugin configuration, you can then have:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <skip><!-- true or the result of a Maven/system property for example --></skip>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: works fine, except for one little thing : the ```configuration``` tag should be inside the ```execution``` tag

Comment: Try -Dmaven.spring-boot.repackage.skip=true

Comment: this did not work until I added the 'id' tag as follows: -  
              <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>repackage</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

Answer (score 2):

It`s works for me

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>repackage</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```